# Как убрать синий экран?

Tags: windows

два дня назад перестала запускаться windows после очередной чистки (возможно было что-то не так удалено), рядом с виндой стоит главной системой Linux, пароль от учетки windows я не помню
Пытался посмотреть файл лога в папке LogFile через linux, но файл открывается в зашифрованном виде
Код остановки windows Critical Service Failed
Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему

Comment: Пробовали с установочной флешки загружаться?

Comment: 1) раз есть линух, из под него сделать резервную копию раздела с системой. 2) оттуда же сделать установочную флешку с той же виндой что установлена (какая у тебя там, 7, 10? и разрядность тоже правильную), 3) загрузиться с нее и попробовать сделать восстановление системы.

Comment: @Gh0sTG0 сказочный полёт мыслей)))

Comment: Который, как ни странно, помог

Comment: Рад, что помогло.